# Accept commas and periods in for input forms Blazor FluentValidation

Tags: c#, validation, blazor

I have several InputNumber fields on a html Blazor page. They essentially track income in the thousands. Many users would prefer to input $10,000 rather than $10000 into these forms, or even $10.000. How can I allow this using Blazor FluentValidation syntax, of course making sure that the user formats their input correctly?

For context, here is the current Validation code for the aforementioned form:

```
 public class BusinessDataValidator : AbstractValidator<BusinessData>
    {
        public BusinessDataValidator()
        {

            RuleFor(p => p.BusinessResellingGross).NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must enter a number");

            RuleFor(p => p.PavementTaxGross).NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must enter a number");

            RuleFor(p => p.CustomWorkServicesGross).NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must enter a number");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you considered adding client-side formatting for those numbers and still only sending across the raw integer (or decimal) value?

Comment: Not specifically, is that the best method?

Comment: When dealing with numeric values, you want to minimize the work you need to do to use them. It's much easier to deal with a single universal number, and apply different formatting to that number on the client, than it is to attempt to handle those various use cases in your server-side code.

Comment: Makes sense, do you have a link or something to get me started though?

Comment: Input masking is likely what you're after. You can see how to do it in this StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541342/blazor-input-mask

Comment: Thank you. That seems to hold the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating your own control for this. The source code for `InputNumber` can be viewed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputNumber.cs)

One common feature of the `Input..` controls is that HTML input comes as a string, and has to be converted from a string input to the bound value type, and back to a string value for display. See `TryParseValueFromString` and `FormatValueAsString`

You can create a copy of `InputNumber` (e.g. `InputCurrency` ?) by copying this code and rewriting these two methods so that the amount is parsed in any way you like.